# Having more than one controller in a view in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building an application that contains a left menu bar, and a main content view which has the attribute `ng-view`. I have configured the router so when the user goes to e.g. `/cars` the html that displays all the cars is used together with the `CarListController`. However, I also would like a controller for the menu-bar (which is the same for all views). Is it right to use the ng-controller attribute on that particular element?

And how about using multiple controllers on the same view (Angular view, the content inside ng-view)? I mean, if you have a created a component such as a contact-form where there are code for events on buttons etc. Instead of duplicating this functionality if you use the contact form inside another view, can you use the ng-controller on that html element containing the contact-form? Is that considered bad usage of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes you can use multiple controller in one view with `ng-controller`
2. It's not a bad practice.
3. If you think it's a component that you can separate to a directive, it would be better. Since directive is all about a component that can do a specific task and it has it's own controller and scope. And It's easier to test too !